# How to display entities contents for all users on JHipster?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm setting up a new micro-service, and want to display entities content without authentication.

How can i display secure data for all users (just Read) and let sign in just for Admin (Create, Read, Update and Delete)?

I don't know where have i to change the code about security and authentication.

`Jhipster` generates all `HTML`, `CSS` and `java` files from my `UML`.

Comment: By "all users", do you mean all authenticated users or all users including non-authenticated ones?

Comment: By all users, i meant all users including non-authenticated ones. I want to list entities content without authentication.

Comment: Have you annotated methods with `@Secured` in your entity resource controller? Hvae you configured authorothies in your angular routes (see https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/#authorizations) ? On gateway have you edited SecurityConfiguration with antMatchers permitAll() on matching your resource endpoint?

Comment: No I don't have annoted methods with @Secured. I tried to edit SecurityConfiguration with antMatchers permitAll() particulary for "/api/**" and "/management/**" but this didn't worked. I haven't configured authorithies in angular routes.

Comment: Well then do it and update your question